# How to write rewrite rule for a directory and its content Nginx EC2

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, url-rewriting

I am new to Webserver configurations etc.

My question is how can I write a rule for a root directory and all the content to that if someone tries directly a not authorised error appears.

[image]

eg in the picture prevent access to ajax and all thats contained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the config below will take care of this: (it is considered that the directory ajax is located in root directory you defined in your nginx config, otherwise you have to specify full address of your ajax directory relative to your root directory.)

```
location ~* /ajax/* {
        return 403;
}
```

Comment: Hello again. This worked great for me but one issue I am having is that my ajax scripts that call these files no longer work. So I I need to give permissions or anything? Thanks

Comment: if your ajax scripts use nginx to access these files so you can't have one config to allow some users to access a url while others get blocked, in this case you need to find a specific pattern to allow and another to block (there should be more details to find a good solution). but if those ajax scripts are running on the same server as nginx, then you have to add some permissions to your files to make them available to the scripts.